# What are here the meanings of the following words "ride trails on mountain sled", "go touring with sport trail" and the others?

Tags: word-meaning

Here is a link to the text's website https://finntrail.com/blog/snowmobile-types/. Here is a small paragraph:

> You may ask yourself… “can I still ride trails on my mountain sled?” of course! It just won’t be the best in class. “Can I still go touring and ice fishing with my sport trail sled?” of course! “Can I go mountain riding with my touring sled?”

I'm not a native English speaker, I'm a translator and I'm translating it from English and these sentences are quite weird to me, so would you please explain it in easier words if it is possible? I did not really get what is a mountain sled, sport trail sled and touring sled is. Are these the types of snowmobiles or what?

And if we are talking about types of snowmobiles I understand what is a mountain, touring and utility snowmobile but what is sport trail I just do not have any idea. Can I say that sport trail is just a sport snowmobile?

Comment: *Mountain sled*, *sport trail sled*, and *touring sled* are all kinds of snowmobiles. They are designed to do different things. 

https://www.mywestshore.com/types-snowmobiles-explained/

Comment: If I use, for example, a sport trail to ride trails, are here trails like small narrow roads or what?

Comment: I've edited your question.  Like your prevous one, you have not checked that it is formatting and so it ends up as one block of text.  Use blank lines between paragraphs and  mark quotes with a ">" at the start of the line.  You can also use the editing tools.  Don't post until you are happy with how your question looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are types of snowmobiles.  I don't know anything about snowmobiles, but that much is clear from the context, the fact that it is an article all about snowmobiles and the author is writing about what type of snowmobile to choose.

It's also clear that "sled" is a slang for snowmobile (again didn't know that until reading the article)

You can read the article to understand about the types: There are "Sport trail" which are good for trail, jumps, going ice fishing. They are probably "sporty" ie fast and manoeuverable.  There are "touring", These are more comfortable but not a fast. And then there are "mountain" snowmobiles, which are powerful and can climb steep slopes.

Again, I'm only repeating what is in the article.

The style of English is "relaxed" and "as if a friend was speaking to you".  This is why there are all the rhetorical questions, and lot of idiomatic spoken-style English.